# Docker, Django, Nginx: Admin cannot be reached HTTP 302

Tags: django, docker, nginx

I am building a Django app in a docker enviroment. This app is served with nginx. I have made an app from scratch. Using docker-compose, I configured two services, the app and nginx. The `default.conf` is pretty simple. Like most tutorials, I passed in server the container name. I set the static the same from the `STATIC_ROOT` of the app.

```
upstream api {
    server sinag_api:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://api;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /static/;
    }
}
```

In the settings, I did not modify much. I just added the `STATIC_ROOT` location. I also modified the allowed hosts.

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]
...
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = "/static/"
```

In my entrypoint for Django, I execute the `collecstatic` command. I can confirm the static files are generated since I inspected the volume.

When I visit the localhost i.e. `127.0.0.1`, I am welcomed by the Django debug web page. However when I visit the admin site `127.0.0.1/admin`, the page cannot be reached. The log in nginx has HTTP 302.

```
nginx      | 192.168.144.1 - - [10/Mar/2023:10:44:25 +0000] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/110.0.1587.63" "-"
```

What causes this problem? I tried both Chrome and Edge for visiting the admin but it is not available. I am not sure what is causing this. I have tried cloning boilerplates from tutorials that seem to work for example: https://github.com/dotja/django-docker-compose but I still cannot reach the admin site.

Added return web page as requested in the comments.

Comment: Where does it redirect?

Comment: But the redirecting of nginx after logging in to the admin page is not an error. It is the usual functionality. I recon your code breaks afterwards. So what is displayed in your browser after logging in to the admin site? Is there also an error thrown by django?

Comment: The site can't be reached. The generic web page. That is the return web page.